# Expected number of HH in 10 coin flips

Tags: probability

This is a simplification of a much more complex problem, but I believe that if I can get the gist of this problem, I can solve the more complicated one. If I flip a fair coin 10 times, what's the expected number of "HH" (counting runs)?

I know that if $T$ is the first time HH is seen, then $\mathbb{E}(T) = 6$. My intuition tells me the answer is $10/6$ but I do not know how to formally show this.

Comment: For clarification, in four flips do you count HHHT as having one or two "HH"s, (*or some other number*)?  You may approach via linearity of expectation on the random variables $X_i$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,9\}$ where $X_i=1$ if positions $i$ and $i+1$ are both heads and zero otherwise.  Assuming the interpretation that the "number of HH" is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 X_i$ then this would give $9\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ as the expected number of HH's.

Comment: @JMoravitz I count that as 2 "HH"s, sorry for the ambiguity. Where did the $1/4$ come from?

Comment: The probability that a specific pair of results both torn up as heads, i.e $ E [X_i] $